# How can I make a swing JButton repeat its action when it is held down?

Tags: java, swing, event-listener

I am creating an touch screen application using Swing and have a request to change one of buttons so that it will behave like a keyboard when the button is held down.
(First of all, I am not sure that the touch screen will allow the user to "hold down" the button, but pretend that they can for now)

I was going to go down the path of starting a loop when `mousePressed` was called and then ending the loop when `mouseReleased` was called.  This will involve starting a thread and having to deal with synchronization as well as `invokeLater()` to get events back on the `EventQueue`.

Is there a very simple way to do what I want?  I hope I am just not seeing the API to do it.

Comment: There is no simple way.  I think what you outlined with a thread doing timed sleeps and polling the button is the only way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) is your friend. And [here's an article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) with some more info.

Comment: That article link is stale.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this:

- Listen to mousePressed and schedule a java.util.Timer to be launched at a later time.
- The Timer does the action and set itself to schedule again.
- Listen to mouseReleased to cancel the Timer.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the java.swing.Timer since it will automatically post back to the Swing EventQueue and that is what I am looking for.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it by subclassing JButton:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TypomaticButton extends JButton implements MouseListener {
    private boolean autotype = false;
    private static Thread theThread = null;
    private String myName = "unknown";
    private int 
        speed = 150, 
        wait = 300,
        decrement = (wait - speed) / 10; 

    TypomaticButton(Action action){
        super(action);
        myName = action.getValue(Action.NAME).toString();
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    TypomaticButton(String text){
        super(text);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));

        myName = text;
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {  }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        autotype = true;
        theThread = new Thread(new Runnable() { // do it on a new thread so we don't block the UI thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 10000; i > 0 && autotype; i--) { // don't go on for ever
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(wait);     // wait awhile
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if(wait != speed){
                        wait = wait - decrement;        // gradually accelerate to top speed
                        if(wait < speed)
                            wait = speed;
                    }
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // run this bit on the UI thread
                        public void run() {
                            if(!autotype)   // it may have been stopped meanwhile
                                return;
                            ActionListener[] als = getActionListeners();
                            for(ActionListener al : als){   // distribute to all listeners
                                ActionEvent aevent = new ActionEvent(getClass(), 0, myName);
                                al.actionPerformed(aevent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                autotype = false;
            }
        });
        theThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        autotype = false;
        wait = 300;
    }

    void speed(int millisecs){
        speed = millisecs;
        decrement = (wait - speed) / 10; 
    }

    void stop(){
        autotype = false;
        if(theThread != null){
            theThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

It accelerates too.

Hope that helps.